# How should recursion be encoded in WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I'm compiling [a language of pure total functions](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Cammy) to WebAssembly. The most complicated construction available is primitive recursion. I have experimented a little, and it seems like the only viable approach is to build a trampolining abstract machine which marches over some sort of bytecode, transforming recursion to iteration. Is there a better strategy?

Comment: I hear that an upcoming GHC release will feature WebAssembly backend support. I would accept an answer which says "compile to Haskell", I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can of course simply use recursion in Wasm, but it will not be tail-recursive. It isn't entirely clear from your question whether that's a requirement.

An extension with explicit tail calls has been [proposed](https://github.com/WebAssembly/tail-call) for Wasm. This proposal is currently at "phase 3" of Wasm's proposal process and has been implemented in V8 and (ongoing) Safari, which means that it will hopefully be standardised very soon.

Until then, yes, you'll have to use some kind of trampoline if you depend on tail call semantics.

Comment: I appreciate this response. Indeed, there are several proposed improvements which would help: multi-argument blocks, basic blocks, GC, and tail calls. I don't depend on tail calls, but my recursion would result in stack overflow if implemented naïvely.

Comment: Well, doesn't that mean that you _do_ depend on it? FWIW, multi-arg blocks are already standard. I'm not sure which proposal you mean by basic blocks, though.

Comment: My semantics are quite abstract; I don't care about call stacks, because categories do not have call stacks. It is WASM, not me, that forces me to avoid calls in order to avoid stack overflow. If WASM had basic blocks or irreducible control flow, then I could just make a soup of blocks which encode some abstract machine, which would be more efficient than interpreting bytecode or reducing a graph.

Comment: I would accept an answer which says "implement the Relooper algorithm," I guess!